# Exclude getopts-options from being read into array by $@

Tags: arrays, bash, scripting

I'm trying to make a script with the following usage:

```
bash script.sh [-a] databases ...
```

The script then populates the array $databases with the arguments from 'databases'

```
databases=("$@")
```

Now I'm trying to implement the option `-a` which if set should declare `att=1`:

```
while getopts "a" o; do
    case "${o}" in
        a)
            att=1
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Now I'm facing the problem that when executing the script `-a` also gets put into the array.

I can't use `read` for the array because I don't have the option to enter additional arguments after the script gets executed as the script will be automated with a RMM and that only lets you enter addition arguments when creating a job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `shift` in `case` block before you populate your variable:

```sh
while getopts "a" o; do
   case $o in
      a)
         att=1
         shift
         ;;
    esac
done

databases=("$@")
declare -p databases att
```

Then run it like this:

```
bash script.sh -a DB1 DB2 DB3
```

**Output:**

```
declare -a databases=([0]="DB1" [1]="DB2" [2]="DB3")
declare -- att="1"
```

Comment: Hmm, I think there's a small misunderstanding. I don't want 'DB1 DB2 DB3' to be the content of `-a` to then populate `$databases`. `-a` should be an option like `-v` for verbose. If `-a` is set the script should check files that would normally not be checked. The problem is that I have the array `$databases` which gets it's content from `$@`, which also includes `-a` as it's own string which produces an array like this: `databases=([0]="DB1" [1]="DB2" [2]="DB3" [3]="-a")`

Comment: ok check my updated answer now

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to manage options with getopts is to do a global `shift` :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while getopts "a" o; do
    case "${o}" in
    a) att=1 ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))

databases=("$@")

declare -p databases att
# output
# ./test.sh -a DB1 DB2 DB3
# declare -a databases=([0]="DB1" [1]="DB2" [2]="DB3")
# declare -- att="1"
```